# Print a quine that contains the input

Tags: code-golf, quine

## Task

You will be given a string in the input consisting only of the characters from `a` to `z`, i.e. the input will match the regex `/^[a-z]*$/`.

Your output should be a complete program in the same language, whose source code contains the input, and is a proper quine.

## Example

Your program would receive the input `abc` and output:

```
...abc...
```

The above should be a complete program in the same language which takes no input and outputs:

```
...abc...
```

i.e. it outputs itself.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

## References

- [What counts as a proper quine?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4877/48934)

Comment: Hmm.. So like a 'quat' (quine + cat)?

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, <s>57</s> 61 bytes

```
lambda x:"s='s=%r;print(s%%s)';print(s%s)".replace('s',x+'x')
```

Takes a basic python 3 quine from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071521/how-does-this-python-3-quine-work) and replaces the variable name with the input.

<s>**Note:** As pointed out by Hyper Neutrino in comments, this does not work for reserved keywords like `for`, `if`, etc.</s>

Appending a character that none of the reserved keywords ends with such as `'x'` or any number fixes this. (Ørjan Johansen).

Comment: Very creative to use the variable name.

Comment: Doesn't work for input `"for"`, or any other reserved word in Python.

Comment: Can confirm. It doesn't work for all possible inputs. [Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PcdRCoAgDADQq4gg2yA6QOFN@jGbIJjJZuDt7a/395I/Zgn3eQUzNqse1DvZm@TaUZ1Tgj9KdhVuJURGUFgGTR4cTcJc29uRaEJ6BD4)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino, Noted, also no idea how to get around it

Comment: You could append an extra character that isn't at the end of any keyword, such as `'x'`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Can't believe I didn't think of that, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

### Generator

```
;“¶Øv”ṾØv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/9qGHOoW2HZ5Q9apj7cOc@IOP////qhaWZeanqAA)

#### How it works

```
;“¶Øv”ṾØv  Main link. Argument: s (string of letters)

;“¶Øv”     Concatenate s and the string "\nØv".
      Ṿ    Uneval; get its string representation.
           (implicit) Print the previous return value since the next link is an
           otherwise unparsable nilad.
       Øv  Set the return value to "Ṙv".
```

### Quine

If the input is `quine`, the following program is generated.

```
“quine
Øv”Ṙv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYU5haWZeKtfhGWWPGuY@3Dmj7P9/AA)

#### How it works

This is the standard Jelly quine. First,

```
“quine
Øv”
```

sets the left argument and the return value to the string `"quine\nØv"`.

Then, `Ṙ` prints a string representation (the code from the previous block) and returns the unaltered string.

Afterwards, `v` takes the left argument and passes it as input to the Jelly program

```
quine
Øv
```

In all Jelly programs, only the *main link* (defined on the last line) is executed, so the first line is ignored entirely.

Finally, `Øv` sets the return value to `"Ṙv"`, which is printed implicitly when the outer program finishes.

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/nUeO@wzPKIh/uBFH///9XLyzNzEtVBwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 51 bytes

`q` takes a string and returns a string.

```hs
q s|t<-"main=putStr$fst`mappend`show$"=t++show(t,s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#y03MzLPNzCtJLUpMLlEo/F@oUFxTYqOrlAsSLygtCS4pUkkrLknITSwoSM1LSSjOyC9XUbIt0dYGsTRKdIo1//8vSS0uAQA)

Example output for `putStr$q"test"`:

```hs
main=putStr$fst`mappend`show$("main=putStr$fst`mappend`show$","test")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@bmJlnW1BaElxSpJJWXJKQm1hQkJqXklCckV@uoqGEV1pJR6kktbhESfP/fwA)

- Puts the main quine text and the desired string in a tuple.
- Uses `fst` to extract the main text.
- Uses `show` to turn the whole tuple into a string.
- Uses `mappend` to combine the two previous functions. Conveniently `mappend` on two functions gives a function that applies each function to its argument and combines the results with `mappend` for the result type (here string concatenation).

Answer (score 4):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), 14 bytes

```
(~aSaS(:^)S):^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/underload#0yhJLS7R/K9RlxicGKxhFacZrGkV9/8/AA)

Use as `(test)(~aSaS(:^)S):^` – which is itself a quine.

## How it works

- Underload is a concatenative (stack-based) esoteric language. It doesn't support reading input, so any arguments are put on the stack initially.
- `(test)` and `(~aSaS(:^)S)` are string literals, so place themselves on the stack, with the latter on top.
- `:` duplicates the `(~aSaS(:^)S)` string on top of the stack, then `^` runs its contents as a subprogram.
- `~` swaps the top two elements on the stack, so now `(test)` is uppermost.
- `a` wraps `(test)` in extra parentheses.
- `S` takes the string `((test))` on top of the stack, and prints it without the outer parentheses (which are just literal syntax).
- Now `aS` prints the remaining `(~aSaS(:^)S)` on the stack similarly (with the parentheses).
- At last, `(:^)S` prints the final `:^`.

Comment: Doesn't really work for `)(` as the input, I think.

Comment: @Riker True, Underload unfortunately doesn't support mismatched parentheses. But the question specifies `a`-`z`.

Comment: Ah, okay. Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 4):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), 14 bytes

```
a(aS(:^)S)~*:^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/underload#00hMSk5J1fyfqJEYrGEVpxmsWadlFff/PwA)

A different approach from the other Underload answer; rather than itself being a quine, this constructs a quine. Interestingly, it comes out to the same number of bytes. This is a function that takes its argument from the stack and outputs to standard output.

### Explanation

```
a(aS(:^)S)~*:^
a               Generate a string literal containing the input
 (aS(:^)S)~*    Prepend "aS(:^)S"
            :^  Mockingbird: run the resulting function with itself as argument
```

The resulting function looks like this:

```
aS(:^)S(input)
aS              Print a string literal containing the argument
  (:^)S         Print ":^"
       (input)  Push "input" onto the stack
```

In other words, it prints a string literal containing itself, followed by `:^`. This is clearly a quine (because what was just printed is the same as the code we executed to run it in the first place).

Comment: It looks like in TIO, you can drop the initial `a`, as long as you don't mind the segmentation fault error printed to stderr when the input contains `a`.

Comment: I didn't even think of just executing the string literal that the user gives, on the basis that the program's work is already finished at that point and without `(` being a character that appears in the input, all programs will necessarily do nothing or crash. I don't even think that's specific to TIO; the program is invalid, but it's already produced the desired output at the time it crashes.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 38 bytes

Though input is only required to support `a-z`, this should work with any single-line input that doesn't contain NUL bytes.

```python
s='s=%r;print s%%s#'+input();print s%s
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19sq15sq1pkXVCUmVeiUKyqWqysrp2ZV1BaoqEJFyz@/189MSlZHQA)

For input `abc` the resulting quine is:

```python
s='s=%r;print s%%s#abc';print s%s#abc
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19sq15sq1pkXVCUmVeiUKyqWqycmJSsDueDuVz//wMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 9 bytes

```
ñ"qPxÉÑ~j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394o1JhQMXhzsMT67L@//dIzcnJBwA)

This is a modification of the [standard V quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100426/31716), and I'm proud that this is only one byte longer.

Hexdump:

```
00000000: f122 7150 78c9 d17e 6a                   ."qPx..~j
```

Explanation:

```
ñ           " Record the following commands into register 'q'
 "qP        " Paste register 'q' before all input
    x       " Delete the last character of what we just pasted (this will be a 'ÿ')
     ÉÑ     " Insert 'Ñ' at the beginning of this line
       ~    " Toggle the case of this character
        j   " Move down a line. During playback, this will cancel playback of the current macro,
            " So everything after here is a NOOP
```

Then, the recording implicitly stops and is played back. This will generate the following output:

```
ñ"qPxÉÑ~jHello
```

Since `j` will break playback of the macro, nothing in `Hello` will ever get run.

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 15 bytes

```
"{']C'.%q[}]C"F
```

### Explained

Using the format

```
{']C'.%q[}]C}
```

where `%q` is the qouted input, builds a quine of the flavour

```
{']C'."Some Text"[}]C
```

which is a standard RProgN2 quine, [`{']C'.}]C`](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn-2#@1@tHuusrlcb6/z//39d3RQA) That, before finished, appends and destroys the inputted string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn-2#@69UrR7rrK6nWhhdG@us5Pb///@QjFSF4pKizLx0hZJ8hcSCgtS8FEUA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 14 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
\(\`^
¶\(*S1`|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x@jEZMQx3VoW4yGVrBhQs3//xUA)

For input `x`, this outputs:

```
\(*S1`|x
\(*S1`|x
```

#### Explanation

The output is a minor modification of the [standard quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67428/8478). We simply use the regex `|x` instead of the empty regex. Since the `|` still allows (and prioritises) and empty match, the functionality itself is not affected, and since `x` will only ever contain letters, it's guaranteed to be valid regex syntax itself.

Printing this actually uses a technique which is similar to the quine itself. To avoid the duplication of the quine, we insert `` ¶\(*S1`| `` only once into the beginning of the string. That's exactly half the source code. To print it twice without a linefeed, we use the configuration `\(\`, which wraps the entire program in a group and makes both the stage itself as well as the group containing it print the result without a linefeed.

Answer (score 1):

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
"\"iQ ²ª`"+U ²
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=IlwiaVEgsqpgIitVILI=&input=ImFiYyI=) For an input of `abc`, outputs

```
"iQ ²ª`abc"iQ ²ª`abc
```

which outputs itself. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=ImlRILKqYGFiYyJpUSCyqmBhYmM=&input=)

#### Explanation

This is an extension of the standard payload-capable Japt quine:

```
"iQ ²"iQ ²

"iQ ²"      // Take this string.  iQ ²
      iQ    // Insert a quote.    "iQ ²
         ²  // Repeat this twice. "iQ ²"iQ ²
            // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

The only difference is that we append `` ª`abc `` at the end, which in JavaScript is basically `||"abc"`. Since the result of the first part is always a non-empty string (truthy), the `||` never gets run.

There are several alternative versions of the same length:

```
"iQ ²ª`abc"iQ ²ª`abc   quine||"abc"
"iQ ²ª$abc"iQ ²ª$abc   quine||abc
"iQ ²ª{abc"iQ ²ª{abc   quine||function(){ ... }
"iQ ²ªXabc"iQ ²ªXabc   quine||X.a(...) (X could be any uppercase letter or digit)
"iQ ²//abc"iQ ²//abc   quine//abc      (// is a comment in JS/Japt)
"iQ ²;[abc"iQ ²;[abc   quine;          (unmatched [ causes a parsing error)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
"`_~"q`';++`_~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@6@UEF@nVJigbq2tDWT9/1@SWlwCAA)

**How it works**

```
"`_~"           e# Push "`_~"
     q`         e# Push a string representation of the input (input wrapped in quotes)
       ';       e# Push a semicolon
         ++     e# Concatenate all this together
           `    e# Get the string representation of the resulting string
            _~  e# Duplicate it and eval it (pushing the original string on the stack again)
```

Which outputs something like `` "`_~\"test\";"`_~"test"; ``.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 21 bytes

```
$=_=>`$=${$}/*${_}*/`
```

Comment: A bit late to say this (it just came up now in the review queue because of CommonMark migration), but this doesn't appear to output a full program.

Comment: It works for me. If you run it with input `abc`, you get ``$=_=>`$=${$}/*${_}*/`/*abc*/``

Comment: I don't actually know JavaScript, but this appears to only be a function, and none of the four JavaScripts on TIO seem to automatically execute it. The challenge spec specifically specifies that "your output should be a complete program". (note that there is no such restriction on the solution itself)

Answer (score 0):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 35 bytes

```perl
$_=q{say"\$_=q{$_};eval"#}.<>;eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rawujixUikGzFKJr7VOLUvMUVKu1bOxAzO5/v8vSS0u@ZdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0AAA)