# Intron Adder Quine

Tags: code-golf, quine

In the context of quines, an intron (or payload) is a part of a quine that serves no purpose in producing output, but is still included in the data section. For example:

```js
function quine() {
    const data = "function quine() {\n    const data=\"@\";\n    // Arr! This be an intron!\n    return data.replace(\"@\", JSON.stringify(data));\n}";
    // Arr! This be an intron!
    return data.replace("@", JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

My challenge is to write a quine that will *normally* run as a standard quine, but if an argument is passed in, then it returns a new quine with the argument placed somewhere in it. If that new quine is called with an argument, it should do the same. For example:

```js
function quine(intron="") {
    const data = "function quine(intron=\"\0\") {\n    const data = \"%%%\";\n    //\0\n    return data.replace(/\u0000/g, intron).replace(\"%%%\", JSON.stringify(data));\n}";
    //
    return data.replace(/\u0000/g, intron).replace("%%%", JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

A few statements:

- If you have no input, then the output should be identical to the source code. If you *have* input, then the output only needs to:

  - Be in the same language
  - Contain the input
  - Be a solution to this challenge in its own right
- Quines only need to contain the latest intron. Introns from the program that generated it are optional.
- If your program already contains the input, then the same program is fine. For example, if it's called with the same input twice.
- The input can be assumed to be printable ASCII only.
- The shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: So with no argument, the program should be a quine, and with an argument the output should be a quine with the argument as a contiguous sublist somewhere in the text?

Comment: @dylnan You can put it anywhere: comments, literals, variable names, as long as you handle any printable ASCII.

Comment: I thought the usual term was `payload`

Comment: @JoKing I got the term "intron" from [this article on quines](http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/quine.html).

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118373/8478)

Comment: "*My challenge is to write a quine that will normally run as a standard quine*" and "*The returned program need only be similar in any way to the original if it's called without arguments*" condradict each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 11 bytes

```
ñéÑvu"qpx:"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///DGwysPTywrVSosqLBS@v/fIzUnJx8A)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: f1e9 d176 7522 7170 783a 22              ...vu"qpx:"
```

This is a simple modification of [the standard V quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100426/31716). Given the input:

```
Hello
```

this program will output:

```
ñéÑvu"qpx:"Hello
```

Which outputs:

```
ñéÑvu"qpx:"Hello
```

This works because the input is automatically appended to the end of `ñéÑvu"qpx`, and `:"` is a comment (essentially)

Comment: Wouldn't a `"` in the input break it?

Comment: @joking Surprisingly, no. `"` is a line comment.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 70 bytes

```python
def f(x=''):s='def f(x=%r):s=%r;print s%%(x,s,x)#%s';print s%(x,s,x)#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNo8JWXV3TqthWHcZVLQJxVYusC4oy80oUilVVNSp0inUqNJVVi9XhgjAxrv9pGuoxQCP@AwA)

A weird extension of the usual python quine `s="s=%r;print s%%s";print s%s`. This adds an extra `%s` after a comment, to output the data, and a `%r` in the default string to push the original string as default instead of an empty string.

Comment: I don't believe this supports input containing both `'` and `"`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Should be fixed

Comment: I don't quite understand the purpose of the `%r` in the default, or of changing `x` in the function. Although it might be related to the question I just asked on the OP (in which case I don't think it actually works if you explicitly pass in the same string again.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 77 bytes

```python
t='';s='t=input()or t;print(f"t={repr(t)};s={repr(s)};exec(s)#{t}")';exec(s)#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8RWXd262Fa9xDYzr6C0REMzv0ihxLqgKDOvRCNNqcS2uii1oEijRLMWqAjCLgayUytSk4EM5eqSWiVNdTj3///EpGR1JXUuAA)

Full programs. Input must be terminated with a newline, and output a trailing newline.

Equivalent Python 2 would be 76 bytes (I think).